# Nginx - How to handle a url that has multiple sub-directories

Tags: nginx

In my app, I have a route /audio/* so any number of audio folders get picked up by the route.  I'm not sure how to handle it in Nginx.  Basically I need to access these files a) that are stored outside of the site root and b) 4 or 5 directories deep.  I can only put in 3 as the alias since the others are not known beforehand.

This is a url

```
10.0.2.2 - - [03/Nov/2017:23:21:33 +0000] "GET /vagrant/TestRails/Music/VA%20-%20Punk%2045%20Chaos%20in%20the%20City%20of%20Angels%20and%20Devils%20(2016)/20%20The%20Hollywood%20Squares%20-%20Hollywood%20Square.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 595 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/audio/vagrant/TestRails/Music/VA%20-%20Punk%
2045%20Chaos%20in%20the%20City%20of%20Angels%20and%20Devils%20(2016)/20%20The%20Hollywood%20Squares%20-%20Hollywood%20Square.mp3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

My site is in `/vagrant/TestRails/MediaExplorer` , the audio files exist in `/vagrant/TestRails/Music/.../`.

Edit: Posting entire server block:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name localhost:8000;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/errorlog debug;
  root       /vagrant/TestRails/MediaExplorer;
  index      /home.slim;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    try_files /system/maintenance.html $uri $uri/home.slim $uri.html @ruby;
   }

   location @ruby {
     proxy_pass http://media_explorer;
   }

   # ** This is the block in question **
   location /audio/ {
     alias /vagrant/TestRails/Music/Album1.....n/files;
     try_files $uri /subfolder/$uri $uri/;
     autoindex on;
  }
```

Is this something that can be done? So far it is not working obviously.  I tried some try_files and while things got completely thrown off, not sure if that is method to use anyway.

Comment: Do you really have stars around the work audio in your location block? I've edited your post a little, but you should make sure anything that's not a comment accurately reflects your configuration.

Comment: No, those stars I thought were for bolding text in my  post.  Taken out.  My route in Sinatra is /audio/* but that is only to make a splat. Inconsequential to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
location /audio/ {
  root /audio/root/path/to/audio/ 
}
```

Comment: took me from a 404 to 500.  I think alias is the right choice.  I have a try_files directive now and the access log "looks" right as far as the get request and headers.  Just 404 comes back.  So, this is outside of the  root / site directory and maybe I need to either move this location to another server block.  Going to update my post with the server block.

Comment: I think this option is viable, but may require tweaking. I serve a whole static website with a location block like that. Serving a directory hierarchy of files is trivial. Root should work. Look in the Nginx error logs, tell me what it says - check permissions for example.

Comment: nothing in the error log and it's on -debug. I mean some earlier stuff, typos, misplacement of directives, etc.  All those are corrected.    Access log shows me the requests and 404's. I'll check permissions, but Nginx is running as vagrant so shouldn't be that problem.

Comment: Well, looking at it I don't think /subfolder in try_files makes much sense ;)   Must need something better, something that corresponds to the alias?  Also going to say is when I was first setting up I had that path as a location and it was able to open the files.

Comment: Well, root works for me, and I believe it's the correct way to serve a folder hierarchy of static files. try_files isn't generally the best way to do this.

Comment: Where does it say it's bad practice? Their [beginners guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) does it regularly and the documentation doesn't seem to say it's a problem.

Comment: [pitfalls and common mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) I might have taken it out of context though, sorry.  It is more about having a root defined outside of the location directives first, and then add exceptions as needed.

Comment: Yep what I've suggested is fine, it's in the "good" section.

Comment: Yes, I removed the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of possible solutions for this.

- Have your application sort out the actual on-disk location of the file and then return an [X-Accel-Redirect](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) to nginx to serve the actual file.
- Use an [overlay filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) to have the files all appear in the same (virtual) directory.

Comment: when you say X-Accel-Redirect, does that mean X-Sendfile would be serving up the file?

Comment: They do the same thing, but different web servers name the feature differently.